# Dynamic Array index create based on level

Tags: php

I need help.

I need to create a dynamic array index of levels.

I have a dynamic value of levels it can be 2,3,4....

if $levels = 5;

i need to create the below array using for loop.

```
$arr['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']['level5']
```

The below code scenario may be helpful to understand the requirement.

```
foreach ($results as $row) { 
   $level = 5; 
   for ($x = 1; $x <= $level; $x++) { 
   /* i need to crete the below format array*/ 
       $arr['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']['level5']
    } 
    $arr['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']['level5'] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I am getting stuck on that, i am adding the code that will help to understand the scenario.  foreach ($results as $row) {
    $level = 5;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $level; $x++) {
        // i need to crete the below format array
        $arr['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']['level5']
    }
    
    $arr['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']['level5'] = $row;
}

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a recursive function, something along the lines of: While you're not at the right level, repeat the function and add another level. It is probably easiest to walk back from the desired and reverse nest:

```
function CreateRowAtDepth($depth = 1, $row='', $outputArr=array()) {
    $outputArr['level'+$depth] = $row;
    $depth--;
    while($depth > 0) {
        $outputArr = nestArray($depth, $outPutArr);
        $depth--;
    }
    return outputArr
}

function nestArray($depth, $outPutArr) {
    return array('level'+$depth => $outPutArr) ;
}
```

And call the function once with the desired depth parameter:

```
CreateRowAtDepth(5, $row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the foreach loop and it will index your results. Example....

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
    echo "<p>This is the key: {$key}</p>"; 
    echo "<p>This is the value: {$value}</p>"; 
}
```

The results will be.

This is the key: 0

This is the value: a

This is the key: 1

This is the value: b

This is the key: 2

This is the value: c

This is the key: 3

This is the value: d

This is the key: 4

This is the value: e

If you want your index to start at 1....

```
$arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
$key = 1;
foreach($arr2 as $answer) {

    echo "<p>Index: {$key} Value: {$answer}</p>"; 
    $key ++;  

}
```

Lastly, since I did not exactly understand if you are trying to get how many results there are into an array, here is another way to do that.

```
$arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
$key2 = 1;
$newArray = [];
foreach($arr2 as $answer) {
    array_push($newArray, $key2);
    $key2 ++;
}
foreach($newArray as $answer) {
    echo $answer;
}
```